# Using WSO2 api manager for one API with multiple backends

Tags: api, wso2-api-manager, endpoint

I want to use wso2 api manager to secure access to my APIs. I have one API that is duplicated in several backends (around 100) (same resources are implemented in all backends). I found that is possible  to use dynamic endpoints  with API manager but my routing policy is depending on the request of the end-user who has the choice to select the endpoint. In this case I cannot define any routing policy (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/adding-dynamic-endpoints/)
Another option is to implement multiple gateways and each gateway will point to one backend (https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/api-gateways-with-dedicated-backends/). However, this option is so complex in my case as I have around 100 backends. Is WSO2 api manager a good option in my case or I should secure my API at the backend level without using API Manager?

Comment: Can you explain more about the use case? How the end-user selects the backend? IMO it has to be based on the request header or some value in the request body. In that case, you should be able to do this using dynamic endpoint.

Comment: This is a somewhat different use case. I don't think you will find a one to one solution if you go with another solution.

Comment: Thanks for  your reply. My use case is that an API is implemented in several backends and in actual state whenever a user wants to use the api of a given backend he needs to specify the ip addresse of the backend server he wants to use: https://ip@/api/v1.0/resource. Now I want to use the API manager to secure access to these APIs for all the backends.

Comment: You can make use of the Dynamic Endpoints concept to achieve your requirement (if the end-users can send an additional header or a param saying that this is the IP address of the Backend). You can create a single API in the API Manager and protect that resource and say the end-users to pass a Header (ex: X-Backend) specifying the IP Address of the Backend server. From the mediation sequence, read the Header, construct the Endpoint URL and send the request. Note that the end-users need to pass a param or a Header to make this work.